# Error to get user group from Active Directory use LDAP in mono

Tags: c#, active-directory, mono, ldap

help me please deal with the problem.

I'm trying to get the user group with the following code. I run through the **mono**. The OS Windows data obtained normally (the account is not included in the domain).  But when I start the same code on Linux get the error.

What do I need to do to obtain a normal result?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ActiveDirectoryTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://sub.domain.com","username@domain","password",AuthenticationTypes.None);                  

                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de);
                search.ReferralChasing=ReferralChasingOption.All;
                search.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))";    

                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
                StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

                var result = search.FindAll()[0];
                int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;

                for (int propertyCounter = 0;
                    propertyCounter < propertyCount;
                    propertyCounter++)
                {
                    var dn = (String) result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];

                    var equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                    var commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                    if (-1 == equalsIndex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("error parse");
                    }
                    groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1),
                        (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                    groupNames.Append("|");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(groupNames.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

> LdapException: (32) No Such Object LdapException: Server Message:
>   0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0,
>   best match of:    ''  Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException

Comment: This does not look like an error in your code, to me it looks like it is an error with communication with the AD / LDAP server.

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually generated when the search base is not valid. When you are using clear-text LDAP (my example below uses SSL, but you can comment out the change the authentication type to System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.None), you can grab a network capture between your application host and the LDAP server on port 389 and *see* the actual search that is being performed.

Per [MS's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2), you should be able to use LDAP://dc=company,dc=gTLD without specifying a specific domain controller. Because I needed my code to be functional with both Active Directory and pure LDAP servers, I use something like LDAP://DomainController.company.gTLD/ou=UserOU,dc=company,dc=gTLD where the LDAP hostname *and* search base is included.

The function I use for LDAP authentication:

```
protected string ldapAuthentication(string strLDAPServer, string strSuppliedUser, string strSuppliedPwd, string strSystemUID, string strSystemPwd, string strLDAPUserBase, string strUIDAttr){
    strSuppliedUser = strSuppliedUser.Trim();
string strResults = "";
    string strLDAPUserHost = strLDAPServer + strLDAPUserBase;

    // Establish LDAP connection and bind with system ID
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry();
    dirEntry.Path = strLDAPUserHost;
    dirEntry.Username = strSystemUID;
    dirEntry.Password = strSystemPwd;

dirEntry.AuthenticationType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;

    try
    {
        dirEntry.RefreshCache();

        // Search directory for the user logging on
        string strLDAPFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(" + strUIDAttr + "=" + strSuppliedUser + "))";
        System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher ldapSearch = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);
        ldapSearch.ServerTimeLimit = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);


        ldapSearch.Filter = strLDAPFilter;
        ldapSearch.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;

        System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection searchResults = ldapSearch.FindAll();


        if (searchResults.Count == 1){
        ...
```

This function is called like:

```
strInputResults = ldapAuthentication("LDAP://DomainController.company.gTLD/", strInputSuppliedUser, strInputSuppliedPwd, "SystemAccount@company.gTLD", "Syst3mP@s5w0rd", "ou=UserOU,dc=company,dc=gTLD","sAMAccountName");
```